# Colour or Font in wxpython.ListBox

Tags: python, fonts, colors, listbox, wxpython

I'm trying to change the colour or the font of a wx.listbox with

```
 testfont = wx.Font(100, wx.MODERN, wx.NORMAL, wx.NORMAL, False, u'')
      self.SetItemFont(1, testfont)
```

but this doesn't work!! I looked in the Internet for a hint but haven't found anything.

Comment: Need a bit more code, is there an error? Do you do this before or adding an item, what type is self (more importantly what does it derive from?)

Answer (score 0):

If you Google around, you will find the following thread:

- http://wxpython-users.1045709.n5.nabble.com/wx-ListBox-SetBackgroundColour-and-SetFont-td2362020.html

According to that thread, Robin Dunn (creator of wxPython) said you will need to override its Show method, like this:

```
def Show(self, show, attr):
     self.choice.Show(show)
     font = self.choice.Parent.GetFont()
     font.SetStyle(wx.FONTSTYLE_ITALIC)
     self.choice.SetFont(font)
     self.choice.SetBackgroundColour(wx.Colour(223, 223, 223))
```

Comment: thanks for your answer! I'm sorry for my bad question. I 'only' want to edit the colour of one item of a listbox (see my example). the SetBackgroundColour in your post works fine, but I cannot use SetItemBackgroundColour... :( do you have an idea how to solve my problem?

Comment: Setting the background and foreground colors of widgets isn't supported across all platforms because wxPython is using the native widget and if the native widget doesn't support it, then wx doesn't support it. You will probably have to create a custom widget to get the effect you want.